Postman Schema Import Validation errors
I am trying to import the generated OpenAPI json file of our API to use this in Postman. During the import postman is showing a lot of validation errors that prevent me from using it.
https://i.sstatic.net/rv5olpkZ.png
Is there anything in the configuration I can add to prevent this?

If Postman is struggling with the OpenAPI, I would first check that the OpenAPI file itself is valid. Any OpenAPI linter tool can be used here, but most of them have default rulesets that might be too strict for your needs.
Here's an example of linting for very basic validity only using Redocly CLI (disclaimer: I work for Redocly so this is not an independent tool recommendation):

Install Redocly CLI

Lint it like this (assuming your file is called openapi.yaml):


redocly lint --extends minimal openapi.yaml

If you see errors, try fixing them before you try using the file with Postman or other tools (you will probably also see some warnings, but start by fixing the errors, is my advice).

Thank you for the suggestion, this returns a similar result:
❌ Validation failed with 10 errors and 86 warnings.
As this is an autogenerated documentation, I wonder how I can fix this during the generation process without the requirement of manual edit every time it is (re)imported?

Check the code and annotations of the source that's being used to generate from, you should be able to make adjustments there to help the generator understand what to output. Alternatively, hand-edit the errors, see if that helps with Postman so you know if it's worth doing the work. Something like Overlays could be added to automatically re-apply changes.
